# what is difference between spring & blueprint & router in apache camel?

Tags: apache-camel, spring-amqp, jbossfuse, apiblueprint

I am new in Fuse. I am using Jboss Fuse and creating Fuse project. 
I want to know basic difference between container like spring, blueprint and router?

Comment: The question is not unclear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring and blueprint are dependency injection frameworks. You use them to configure all the dependencies you will use in your JBoss Fuse application (just as `jms` queues or java `Datasources`).

Spring is a popular framework, whereas blueprint is OSGi-specific (that's why it is used in JBoss Fuse).

A router controls the flow of messages in your application. JBoss Fuse is built upon the `Apache Camel` lightweight integration framework, which does your routing. When you write a JBoss Fuse application, you will likely be defining `Routes` via Java or XML.

To read more about routing, I suggest you read about *Enterprise Integration Patterns* on the apache camel web site.